# How to stop NSTimer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nstimer

Hey so i am just making an example application and i am having a little trouble, So i have a table view and then i have a few rows and when a user clicks a row it takes them to a new view. On this view i have a button to play music. I am using a timer to make a slider bar increase based on music duration and remaining time.

Now my problem is, what do i have to put so that when i go back to the table view via the top left button, that the NSTimer stops?

this is what i have so far, i cannot get a repeat: YES timer to stop.

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize lbl1;
@synthesize timer;

-(IBAction) slide {
 myMusic.currentTime = slider.value;
}

-(IBAction)play
{
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 slider.maximumValue = [myMusic duration];
 myMusic.volume = 0.2;
 [myMusic prepareToPlay];
 [myMusic play];
}

-(IBAction)pause
{
 [myMusic pause];
}

-(IBAction)stop
{
 slider.value = 0;
 myMusic.currentTime = 0;
 [myMusic stop];
}

- (void)updateTime{
  slider.value = myMusic.currentTime;
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {

  //This plays music, we must give it a path to find the file and then u can change it. 
 NSString * pathToMusicFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Katy" ofType:@"mp3"];
     myMusic = [[ AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMusicFile] error:NULL];
     myMusic.delegate = self;
     myMusic.numberOfLoops = -1;

 slider.value = 0;
 //[myMusic play];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {

 [timer invalidate];
 timer = nil;
 //myMusic.currentTime = 0;
 [myMusic stop];
 [super viewDidUnload];

 // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
 // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

-(IBAction) TxtChange;{

 lbl1.text = @" test2! I CHNAGED TEXT FROM ANOTHER XIB";
}

- (void)dealloc {
 [timer invalidate];
 timer = nil; 
 [myMusic release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 68):

Use the below code. It will work
But keep in mind that it must only be called if our timer is in running mode else the application will get crashed.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    //BEFORE DOING SO CHECK THAT TIMER MUST NOT BE ALREADY INVALIDATED
    //Always nil your timer after invalidating so that 
    //it does not cause crash due to duplicate invalidate
       if(timer)
       {
         [timer invalidate];
         timer = nil;
       }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: I am going to go try this in the morning, its 2 AM, been stuck on this all day. Hopefully your solution works. ill get back to this post in a few hrs.

Comment: somebody should tell him he's about 3 years late on that whole getting back to you thing... Either way, fixed my issue!

Comment: Be very careful with stopping your timer in viewWillDisappear.  This is not called if your app goes into the background.  And you probably want to stop your timer in that case to avoid the OS killing your app.

Answer (score 13):

like this:

```
[yourtimername invalidate];
```

But be careful, you cant stop the timer if it's already stopped because your app will crash.

Comment: The app don't crash when i invalidate a timer not instantiated.

Answer (score 8):

As iCoder says it has to be invalidated in viewWillDisappear.

I added the following just to make sure. it works for me. Hope it helps (and adds to icoders answer do not intent to copy)

```
- (void) startTimer
{
[self stopTimer];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 5.0
                                                     target: self
                                                   selector:@selector(onTick)
                                                   userInfo: nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void) stopTimer
{
    if (timer) {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

4 year old post, I know but maybe I can save the NEXT guy from wasting time trying invalidate a NSTimer. Apples documentation explains it and it works for me.

in .h

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *yourTimer;
@property(weak) NSTimer *repeatingTimer;
```

in .m

```
@synthesize yourTimer, repeatingTimer;
```

in viewDidLoad

```
yourTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimerInterval)(40.0/60.0)
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(blink)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:TRUE];

  self.repeatingTimer = yourTimer;
```

in my viewDidDisappear

```
   [repeatingTimer invalidate];
   repeatingTimer = nil;
```

the trick is in the assignment of the first NSTimer to (weak) NStimer object and killing THAT object.

Answer (score 2):

You Could Use Two Different Things

```
    [timername invalidate];
```

Or You Could Use

```
    timername = nil;
```

Comment: The latter one won't actually stop the timer, and the first one was already posted in August 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Trick is to use a singleton class,
google myGlobals class which is mostly used as a singleton
Although if u do wish to use `NSTimer`, then

lets say the view 1 is which u go into and view 2 is the one which u go back 2.

So in case of view 2, write the `NSTimer` to invalidate the timer in the `viewDidLoad`(Assuming you have two separate classes for both views).Problem will occur because when u go to view 1, the view 2 Timers will be dealloc. So, make a Singleton class and save the `NSTimer` pointer like this

```
//to be done in viewDidLoad function
theGlobals *globals = [theGlobals alloc] init];// for the singleton class to initiate,
[globals.myTimer invalidate];


//to be done in viewDidUnload
theGlobals *globals = [theGlobals alloc] init];// for the singleton class to initiate,
globals.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 5.0
                                                 target: self
                                               selector:@selector(onTick)
                                               userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
```

oh , and here is the myGlobals class code that u will need

```
//theglobals.h file

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface theGlobals : NSObject 
{
    NSTimer *myTimer;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *changeyes;



+(theGlobals*)sharedInstance;
@end

//implementaton .m file

#import "theGlobals.h"
@implementation theGlobals

@synthesize myTimer;



static theGlobals *sharedInstance;

- (id) init
{
return self;
}

+(theGlobals*)sharedInstance
{
if (!sharedInstance)
{
    sharedInstance = [[theGlobals alloc] init];
}
return sharedInstance;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just invalidate the timer

[timer invalidate];