# problem with the counter of a collision between two images

Tags: iphone, xcode, timer, uiimageview, collision-detection

here is my code :

```
-(void)collision {

    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(imageView.frame,centre.frame)){

        [imageView removeFromSuperview];
        count++;
        label.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", count];
    }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(collision) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    count=0;    
    scale=1;
}
```

with this code my count increase of more than one sometimes 34 and sometime 74 or 70 , why ?

Comment: Why `count==0`? Is it mistake? Try `count=0`. And also use `++something` instead of `something++`, it's faster.

Answer (score 1):

> Stops the receiver from ever firing
>   again and requests its removal from
>   its run loop.

```
 - (void)invalidate
```

[class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

[helpful question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509012/how-to-stop-nstimer-scheduledtimerwithtimeinterval-time-userinfonil)

Comment: why invalidate, I don't wanna stop my timer ?

Comment: @bernard langue ok, i'm not an expert at iOS multithreading. But. You don't stop the timer and the view can not be removed immediately. And. As the image is removed, there's no good reason to call the selector hundred times a second. My proposition is to start the timer only when you need to use it and to stop it immediately after. I believe can also use several timers.

Comment: how can I do "start the timer only when you need to use it and to stop it immediately after"

Comment: [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(collision) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 starts the timer and - (void)invalidate stops it, doesn't it ? Start/stop points depend on your app behavior, if you need to leave the timer working, you can try to set the label text with the counter *before* removing the view, hope it helps.