# How to stop an NSTimer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have an NSTimer that I want to be stopped when I leave my `vViewVontroller`:

The timer is in a method that I call from `viewWillAppear` :

```
- (void) myMehtod
{
    //timer = [[NSTimer alloc] init];
    // appel de la methode chaque 10 secondes.
     timer  =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0f
                                     target:self selector:@selector(AnotherMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    //self.timerUsed = timer;
}
```

I call the method stopTimer in `viewWillDisappear`

```
- (void) stopTimer
{
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

PS: I tried the answer of user1045302 in this question but it didn't work:

[How to stop NSTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509012/how-to-stop-nstimer)

Comment: How is `timer` declared? Is it a `@property` of your class, an instance variable? If you put a breakpoint at the start of `stopTimer`, is it even called? What value has `timer` at this point?

Comment: when you back to viewcontroller at that time you can call [self stoptimer];

Comment: How do you know that the timer isn't stopping?

Comment: Call `stopTimer` from the main thread. `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self stopTimer];
    });`

Comment: @Cyrille :  timer is declared in my viewcontroller just like this:  NSTimer *timer;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source of the problem probably is that `myMehtod` is called twice or more times.

Since the method does not invalidate existing timers before setting up the new one you actually have several timers ticking at the same time.

Fix is easy: invalidate old timers before setting up a new one:

```
- (void)myMehtod
{
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0f
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(anotherMethod)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the most logical explanation.

Comment: Yes...this is logically the best explaination