# How to set the timers in [NSTimer] to nil?

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

The goal is to fire timers when selecting a row in a tableView and in the same time getting rid of the old timers. As I don't want to leave anything in memory I guess invalidating them isn't enough. The new timers may be different (I've simplified the code here), so I don't want to re-use them.

I'm trying to set the timers in an array to `nil` but on the line `timer = nil` Xcode gives an error.

```
class DataModel() {
  var timers = [NSTimer]()
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

  var dataModel = DataModel()

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if dataModel.timers.count != 0 {
      for timer in dataModel.timers {
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = nil  //"Cannot assign to value: timer is a let constant."
      }
    }

    for i in 0...10 {
      var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(i), target: self, selector: "doSomething", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
      dataModel.timers.append(timer)
    }
  }    
}
```

I've tried making the timer instances optionals `NSTimer?` but that also does not work, I may be doing something wrong here in the `for timer in dataModels.timer` line. Would I need an `if let` construction?

```
class DataModel() {
  var timers = [NSTimer?]()
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

  var dataModel = DataModel()

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if dataModel.timers.count != 0 {
      for timer in dataModel.timers {
        timer!.invalidate()
        timer = nil // Error here
      }
    }

    for i in 0...10 {
      var timer = NSTimer?()
      timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(i), target: self, selector: "doSomething", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
      dataModel.timers.append(timer)
      //timer = nil // No error here.
    }
  } 
}
```

Setting `dataModel.timers = []` certainly wouldn't be enough I guess, as it would just clear the array but leave the timer instances intact.

What would be the best way to solve this?

Comment: use [timer invalidate] ; timer = nil ;

Comment: this link may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/29980704/5362916

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are in a loop, where you cannot mutate the object that is being iterated.

```
for timer in timers {
    // timer is initialized here like "let timer = timers[index]"
}
```

Invalidate the the timers in the loop, then set

```
timers = nil
```

or

```
timers.removeAll()
```

Comment: OK, this seems to be the way to go. If you add that I have to change the timers array to be optional `var timers = [NSTimer]?()` I will accept this as the answer. After `timers = nil`, is there anything left of these timers in memory?

Comment: Nope, they will be deleted if you don't have reference to them somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically invalidating and killing all the timers and then recreating them all, so just empty the array in-between the 2 loops with `removeAll(keepCapacity:)`.

Comment: Does this still apply when the new timers are a completely new set of a different number of timers with different intervals (obviously I wouldn't need the (keepCapacity:) )? As I've simplified the code here. I really wouldn't need the old timers any more and thus want to lose them.

Comment: yes, so you can remove them all from the array. you don't need to actually destroy the array too, just remove all the now invalid timers from it

Answer (score 1):

can you just invalidate and then remove from the array? how come you need optional timers in the array?

```
array.forEach{
  $0.invalidate()
}
array.removeAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not set a local scope variable not nil in Swift since it is not a `var` but a `let`.

Just `nil` the timers variable after the loop.

Comment: I'm not sure if understand you correctly. Do you mean making the timers array an optional and then setting the array to nil? Would this effectively kill all the timers memory usage? Would I still have to invalidate each timer first?