# How to restart or stop a Timer in Swift without destroying it?

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I'm developing an iOS application using a bluetooth device with a button that is communicating with the iPad. Basically I want a help request to be issued when the button is held for 3 seconds or longer.

From all the documentation I found, I couldn't find a way to stop a Timer without invalidating it, with the *invalidate()* method. From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer):

> The run loop then removes the timer (and the strong reference it had to the timer), either just before the 
>   invalidate()
>    method returns or at some later point. **Once invalidated, timer objects cannot be reused.**

So the idea in my code is that when the button is pressed, the boolean *buttonWasHeld* is set to true and a timer is fired. If the button is released, *buttonWasHeld* is set to false and, when the timer calls the handler it knows the button wasn't held long enough. Then if the button is pressed again within the 3 seconds, the timer is set over again.

Problem is: every button press makes a new timer, which means that repeatedly pressing the button will also issue the help request. Furthermore, all those timers are addressed by the same variable so I can't tell them apart.

Is there a way to uniquely tell what was the last timer created? Or an obscure way to pause/stop it?

Here's the piece of code controlling this feature:

```
var buttonTimer: Timer?
var buttonWasHeld: Bool = false

func didUpdateModule() {
    // gpioListener takes a handler to be called whenever a button is
    // pressed or released. isPushed is a self-explanatory boolean.
    self.controller.gpioListener() { isPushed in
        if isPushed {
            self.buttonWasHeld = true
            self.buttonTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: false) { _ in
                if self.buttonWasHeld {
                    // Issue a help request
                    self.delegate?.notifyDevice(message: .HELP)
                    print("Asking for help")
                }
            }
            print("Button was pressed")
        }
        else {
            self.buttonWasHeld = false
            // Also tried "self.buttonTimer = nil" here. Didn't work
            print("Button was released")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop NSTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509012/how-to-stop-nstimer)

Comment: The solution there was exactly what I'm looking to avoid, invalidating the timer. It will make this Timer unusable.

Comment: What about each time you want to create a new timer, check if the timer stored in `buttonTimer` has been invalidated using `isValid`. If it has been invalidated, create a new one, otherwise use the current one.

Comment: I tried that too, @Sweeper ... Not very successful

Answer (score 2):

As usual, the answer was quite simple.

If the Timer is declared as a *weak var*, and not just *var*, only the weak instantiation will be invalidated. So the code should be:

```
weak var buttonTimer: Timer?
var buttonWasHeld: Bool = false

func didUpdateModule () {
    (...)
        else {
            // This will only invalidate the current running timer,
            // not the whole variable :)
            self.buttonTimer.invalidate
            // I removed buttonWasHeld, it's not necessary anymore ;)
            print("Button was released")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The other solutions weren't quite right. Thanks for posting this - the 'weak' was all I needed. +1